# How to stop messages from going to Dead LetterQueue(DLQ) in Activemq after re-delivery policy

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, dead-letter

```
private BrokerService createBroker() throws IOException, Exception {
         BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();KahaDBStore kaha=new KahaDBStore();
         File file =new File(path);
         TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();
         connector.setUri(new URI(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL));
         kaha.setDirectory(file);
         broker.addConnector(connector);
         broker.setPersistenceAdapter(kaha);
}
```

This is configuration for my broker. Can somebody specify the configuration, how I can stop messages from going to DLQ after my re-delivery policy?

Note : I have already visited this, http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

Answer (score 2):

The question is - what do you want to do with them instead?

**Just drop them after all redelivery attempts has been exhausted?**

Configure the discard plugin

```
<deadLetterStrategy>
   <discarding/>
</deadLetterStrategy>
```

or by Java

```
PolicyEntry policy = new PolicyEntry();
policy.setDeadLetterStrategy(new DiscardingDeadLetterStrategy());
PolicyMap policyMap = new PolicyMap();
policyMap.setDefaultEntry(policy);
broker.setDestinationPolicy(policyMap);
```

**Never exhaust redelivery and try until the message is through?**

This may be problematic beacuse of poision messages - i.e. messages with corrupt payload that never can be processed and has to be removed to not interrupt the flow. If you want this anyway, configure a client side `maximumRedelivery` to -1 ([see docs](http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html)).

Comment: Can you add to the existing configuration. I dont really use xml configuration. I use Java based configuration. 
I want the messages to be discarded after retries rather than go to DLQ.

Comment: Is it possible to discard only a certain messages with a pattern by configuring in activemq.xml ?

Comment: @Pathfinder nah, for that you probably need to use the broker Camel component, https://activemq.apache.org/broker-camel-component. It's VERY powerful though so you should be able to do whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(-1);
```